# SQLiteException because of ' char, how to escape it?

Tags: android, sqlite

When my `EditText` contain " ' " char I have `SQLiteException` because of it. Do I need to escape the char, if so, how to do that quickly?

```
public Cursor getAll() {
        return(getReadableDatabase()
                .rawQuery("SELECT _id, " + 
                        COLUMN_NAME_ONE + ", " +
                        COLUMN_NAME_TWO + ", " +
                        COLUMN_NAME_THREE + ", " +
                        COLUMN_NAME_FOUR + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null));
```

Comment: You should pass your EditText as a parameter to the query.  Consult the documentation for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `android.database.DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(sql_string);`

Answer (score 0):

Escape it by adding \ in front of it (so \" instead of ") inside the string.

You can use
    replaceAll(char oldChar, char newChar) to replace ' by \' and escape it.

Comment: Any method to add \ to an existing string before ' char?

Comment: Could you show the specific situation? I don't see the problem in adding the \ escape character in front of the " characters?